# PowerShell: Modify HTML website

Tags: html, powershell, html-table

I saved a copy of a webpage via powershell (IE com-object) and now I would like to modify the source code. I would like to remove the first row of the table (TR-TAG), see source code at: http://pastebin.com/kqfQUsHR (see line 17 and 44).
How can I accomplish this in powershell?

Comment: I can't see any source code !

Comment: Sorry, I did not express myself clearly. I wrote a powershell script which saves the content of this page (and several subpages) to html-files. I made some changes to the html file, e. g. removing unneeded text "Antwort...", but my problem now is that I can not delete the TR-tag because I have nothing unique to identify it - so that the script does not delete the other TR-tag. I hope you understand me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to change the HTML code of the webpage, to fix the double table border between the header and the page itself (remove the TR tag).

Patrick, if that is what you want to fix, your web pages are build dynamically (php), so you need to change this in the php script that makes the web page(arbeitsblatt.php).